# How to print the position

Tags: c++, string

Since x_str,y_str are local, I am not getting the correct output in this function.   (Illegal chars are printed in the place of x_str and y_str) 
I dont want to add 2 more member variables x_str,y_str to my class.

Hence what could be the replacement of this function to get correct output.

```
string Pos::getPosReport(){
        string x_str;
        x_str = x;
        string y_str;
        y_str = y;
       return string("(" + x_str + "," + y_str + ")" );
    }
```

EDIT:

```
class Pos {
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    Pos();
    Pos(Pos const&);
    Pos(int,int);

    Pos&     operator=(Pos const&);
    bool    operator==(Pos const&);
    bool    operator!=(Pos const&);

    void    setPos(Pos const&);
    void    setPos(int,int);

    void    setx(int);
    void    sety(int);

    int    getx() const ;
    int    gety() const ;

    string getPosReport();

    virtual ~Pos();
};
```

Comment: The question is not clear. What is your actual problem to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "(" << x << "," << y << ")";
return ss;
```

(this is the whole function body).

Comment: My compiler gives error for `std::stringstream ss;
return (ss << "(" << x << "," << y << ")").str(); ` **Error : ‘struct std::basic_ostream<char>’ has no member named ‘str’**  but    `stringstream s;
   s << "(" << x << "," << y << ")";
   return s.str();`
comipiles correctly. Thanks for your response.

Comment: This doesn't work because `operator<<` returns a reference to an ostream, and ostream does not have a member function `str()`.

Comment: Oops, my fault. Thanks for fixing, @EAGER_STUDENT.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't that `x_str` and `y_str` are local variables, but that the assignments don't do what you expect them to do. That's not you convert an `int` to a `string`.

You can use `_itoa()` to convert an `int` to a `char*` or a `stringstream` as in Michael's answer.

Comment: The int is being cast to char for which operator= is defined. The string contains just the single char.

Comment: @sftrabbit if you have the int 1, it won't be cast to the char `'1'`.

Comment: (This was in response to your previous, removed comment: "Is that standard?") Yes, I believe so. If the value of the int doesn't fit in a char, the result will be implementation defined. If the implementation defines char to be signed, the cast will also be implementation defined.

Comment: Casting an int with value 1 to a char, the char will also have value 1. The character that this then represents is locale-specific.

Comment: If we are to list all solutions, I'd also mention `autoprintf` that comes with gettext.

Comment: Sorry, misread the comment. I didn't mean to imply that a char with value 1 being assigned to a string would create a string with the character '1'. The string will have the character with value 1.